# Is it possible to extend the disk space available to a wubi install?

Tags: wubi, disk

I installed ubuntu 10.04 using wubi. I now wish to allocate more disk space to my ubuntu install. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

[From the WubiGuide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How%20do%20I%20resize%20the%20virtual%20disks?):

> ## How do I resize the virtual disks?
>
> You can use LVPM, at
> http://lubi.sourceforge.net/lvpm.html
>
> As an alternative, you can use the
> following script to move /home to a
> dedicated virtual disk.
>
> Download wubi-add-virtual-disk, open a
> terminal and run:
>
> ```
> sudo sh wubi-add-virtual-disk /home 15000
> ```
>
> Where the first argument is the
> directory to move to a new dedicated
> disk, and the second argument is the
> size in MB.
>
> You should now reboot. If you are
> happy with the result, you can now
> remove /home.backup. To undo the
> changes remove /home, copy rename
> /home.backup to /home and remove the
> /home line in /etc/fstab.
>
> Note that contrary to previous
> information, this script is not
> suitable for moving /usr - experienced
> users may be able to do this manually,
> at own risk, following a process
> similar to that outlined in the file.
> (Do not rename /usr until the very
> last moment, as rsync is installed
> there.)

Comment: "LVPM currently does not work with installs generated by Wubi 10.04"

Comment: There is an update in the Wubi Guide that has a link to a newer Howto (and script) for resizing a current Ubuntu install: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1625371

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options to resize. Source the [Wubi Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_resize_the_virtual_disks.3F).

You can resize by making a duplicate, larger `root.disk`. The downside is that it doesn't help if you're short on space and it takes a little longer. On the plus side, you have a backup to make sure everything worked and you run it right from the Wubi install.

The other method is to dynamically resize the `root.disk` in place. The downside is you have to do it from a Live CD/USB, you don't automatically get a backup, and there's no helper script. The plus side is it's blazingly fast and you can increase by a couple of GB rather than find space to duplicate++.

Both methods are documented in the Ubuntu community Wiki.

It's also possible to create a separate virtual disk for your `/home` directory. This is not discussed here, but can be found in the [Wubi Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_resize_the_virtual_disks.3F).

**Resize and Duplicate the `root.disk`**

First download the script [wubi-resize-1.6.tar.gz](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=wubi-resize-1.6.tar.gz) from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk to your Downloads directory, right-click and choose "Extract here". The rest of the resize is run from the Terminal.

For usage instructions:

```
cd ~/Downloads/wubi-resize-1.6
bash wubi-resize.sh --help
```

To create a new 10GB virtual disk:

sudo bash wubi-resize.sh 10

[image]

See the Wiki documentation for more information, including how to verify the integrity of the script. Also, note that there's a built-in maximum for the new disk (32GB), but this can be overridden with the `--override-max` option. (I don't recommend making the `root.disk` too large because many Wubi installs suffer from corruption and sometimes the data is not recoverable`. It's better in this case to use shared data partitions or to [migrate to a normal dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/635/14916).

**In-place resize of the `root.disk`**

If you don't have enough space to do a full duplicate, you can do an in-place resize instead. For this you have to boot from a live CD/USB as it won't work while running Wubi. Although not required, it's a good idea to backup the `root.disk` or the data on it. (This is a good idea for any Wubi install as it's not as reliable as a normal install).

Mount the NTFS partition that your root.disk is on (this example assumes it's `/dev/sda1` and the mountpoint is `/media/win` - adjust accordingly in the following instructions):

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/win
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/win
```

Check the size of the root.disk (not required):

```
du -h --apparent-size /media/win/ubuntu/disks/root.disk
```

Run fsck on the root.disk:

```
fsck -f /media/win/ubuntu/disks/root.disk
```

Resize - specify the desired final size (this example resizes to 10 GiB):

```
resize2fs /media/win/ubuntu/disks/root.disk 10G
```

Reboot back into Wubi Ubuntu. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeWubiDisk for more information.