# Increase space for /root in Ubuntu Wubi

Tags: wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to extend the disk space available to a wubi install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2465/is-it-possible-to-extend-the-disk-space-available-to-a-wubi-install)

I have ubuntu 10.04 installed inside Windows 7 through Wubi. I need to increase the size of /root or root.disk. How can I do this? wubi-add-virtual-disk does not work since root.disk is already present.

Answer (score 3):

Found this information [on the wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide):

> **How do I resize the virtual disks?**
>
> You can use LVPM, at http://lubi.sourceforge.net/lvpm.html
>
> As an alternative, you can use the following script to move /home to a dedicated virtual disk.
>
> Download [wubi-add-virtual-disk](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=wubi-add-virtual-disk), open a terminal and run:
>
> ```
> sudo sh wubi-add-virtual-disk /home 15000
> ```
>
> Where the first argument is the directory to move to a new dedicated disk, and the second argument is the size in MB.
>
> You should now reboot. If you are happy with the result, you can now remove /home.backup. To undo the changes remove /home, copy rename /home.backup to /home and remove the /home line in /etc/fstab.
>
> Note that contrary to previous information, this script is not suitable for moving /usr - experienced users may be able to do this manually, at own risk, following a process similar to that outlined in the file. (Do not rename /usr until the very last moment, as rsync is installed there.)

So, essentially you do need to create a new disk, move your data over to it (it seems like this script might do that for you, but I'm not completely sure) and then remove the backup image when you're satisfied.

Comment: I am able to extend the size of my home drive using this. But I am not able to extend the size of /root or root.disk.