# How do I increase the size of Ubuntu which was installed through Wubi?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-7, wubi

First, this is question is not same as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35401/how-do-i-give-ubuntu-more-space-when-installed-inside-windows-7-via-wubi) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4190/increase-space-for-root-in-ubuntu-wubi). It is similar but its somewhat different in a way. Particularly,  I want to change the path of where my disk copy is generated. The problem is: I know I have another drive where I have a lot of space and I want a new (resized) copy of my Ubuntu to be generated at that path and then remove the older copy after verifying that my new copy boots correctly. Currently my Ubuntu is of 30 gigs and is at drive H:\, I want to increase it to 40 gigs (actually 50 gigs would be great but my H:\ partition is of 50 gigs and would be requiring to have some free space for swap). I want to store the intermediate copy in drive E:. I want to do this because my H:\ drive is 50 gigs (26 gigs filled) and so I can't create a copy in the same drive. Is it possible to do that by, say, modifying the script given [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=wubi-add-virtual-disk)? Or is there any other way to do that?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you should consider Ubuntu dual boot system, way better than using Wubi..

Comment: Ya, I'd love to but I don't know how to backup and restore the current installation.

Comment: please see if this helps: [Easy backup/restore of installed system?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13278/easy-backup-restore-of-installed-system)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you found the steps to migrate and resize your WUBI installation, the maximum size is 30GB -by design limitation; which you are already configuring.

If you need a bigger size for your Ubuntu installation, then The answer will be backing up your system\data > perform another installation on a dedicated partition or perhaps a virtual machine > restore your data to.

You can also migrate your WUBI installation to a partition by following this article http://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi

But I'm afraid I didn't try it before