# How can I make the Wubi installation partition bigger? 

Tags: 11.10, dual-boot, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to extend the disk space available to a wubi install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2465/is-it-possible-to-extend-the-disk-space-available-to-a-wubi-install)

I'm on Ubuntu 11.10, I just want to make the Wubi installation partition bigger. Is there any way? I use dual-boot with Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Is this not the moment to install Ubuntu at is own partition, this meanes migrate your wubi install to a partition.  You can find here all the necessary: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1519354 .  I would recommend it.