# How can I increase the space of /home without losing my data?

Tags: 12.04, wubi, home-directory

I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, installed via Wubi on a Windows 7 machine. My HDD is 1 TB. When I installed via Wubi I used the maximum 30 GB installation size. Since then, I have decided I want to make Ubuntu my primary operating system. So my question is, how do I increase the size of `/home` without losing my data?

While I'm not a total noob to Linux I am by no means an advanced user.

I downloaded ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso from Ubuntu.com, made a bootable disk out of my USB drive, and started up the "trial version" of Ubuntu. I ran the installer until I got to this screen

[image]

I didn't want to install in Windows - that's what I already have through wubi and what I'm trying to fix. Nor do I want to replace Windows because there are still a few tasks here and there that I still need it to run. So I clicked the "Something else" option. I was greeted with this screen

[image]

I know virtually nothing about partitions because I've never had to mess with them before. So I clicked "Install now" and prayed that it would work.
Instead, I got this error message

[image]

Like I said in my first edit, I'm by no means an advanced user, but you seem to know quite a bit about partitions, so can you help me?

Comment: If you want to run Ubuntu as your main operating system, you should reinstall on a dedicated partition. Put the CD in, install, then mount the NTFS partition, then the Wubi image and copy your data.

Answer (score 0):

You could boot a Knoppix DVD and resize the NTFS partition Ubuntu is stored in a file on. After resizing it, you can create a ext4 partition in the free space. Now you can boot Ubuntu and copy all your /home to the new partition. You would now be able to delete /home on the old Wubi partition, add the new partition in /etc/fstab, and you would have migrated your /home to a real partition with more space.

Comment: Why knoppix?  The Ubuntu live CD will run programs like gparted and they can do this task.

Comment: The live CD would work too. I like Knoppix cause it was designed for CD booting.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to switch to real partitions (which are IMHO better, since they would give you superior performance), you can extend your Wubi parition size: [Is it possible to extend the disk space available to a wubi install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2465/is-it-possible-to-extend-the-disk-space-available-to-a-wubi-install)