# How do I extend my disk space with wubi?

Tags: wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to extend the disk space available to a wubi install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2465/is-it-possible-to-extend-the-disk-space-available-to-a-wubi-install)

i install ubuntu 12.04 a couple of months ago. i use the maximum space allowed in ubuntu which is 30g to install ubuntu. Because of ubuntu's updates my disk is now on low space. i wish to add more.. maybe another 50g to make it 80g. Ive seen some tutorial about wubi resize1.5b. BUt i dont know why it says this:

```
skadush@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo bash wubi-resize_1.5b.sh 80
wubi-resize_1.5b.sh: The new disk cannot exceed 32 GB unless the
wubi-resize_1.5b.sh: --max-override option is used (not recommended).
```

Please help.. I realy want to extend may disk space on ubuntu.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

32 Gig should be more then enough for a wubi install with a small home directory. If you need significantly more you should probably do a full install of ubuntu, not wubi.

Since you said that the disk space is low because of updates you might want to try running `sudo apt-get clean; sudo apt-get autoremove` which will remove old files update files and programs that were automatically installed but are no longer needed.

Comment: 4mb freed.. wow..

Comment: @thenewbie again. if you need more then 32gigs you should probably just do a full install of ubuntu, wubi is for people that just want to try it out, or for light use. You could also try making the disk bigger then 32 gigs by using running `sudo bash wubi-resize_1.5b.sh --max-override <desired size>` like Dave Sousa suggests.

Comment: yeah i will do that. ahm is it safe? is there any chance that my ubuntu wil not work anymore because of that?

Comment: @thenewbie I do not believe there will be any danger. Wubi appears to create a new copy of the disk. To finish moving to the bigger disk you must manually rename the disks from in windows. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk#Automated_resize

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `sudo bash wubi-resize_1.5b.sh 80` type `sudo bash wubi-resize_1.5b.sh --max-override 80`.

Make sure the 50GB, next to your Ubuntu partition, are free.

Comment: is it safe? do i have to back up all my files?

Comment: Nothing is safe, when managing disks. If you do not feel secure about modifying the partition, you should backup. If you trust nothing will happen, then do it. I never do backups and have been messing with partitions for years. Could be just luck or carefulness with the steps I take. Good luck!

Comment: I just increased my root disk file to 100GB from 30GB. It worked perfectly. wubi-resize makes a new root disk (new.dsk) copies all the files in it from current root disk to it and then asks you to go to windows and rename root.dsk to OLDroot.dsk and new.dsk to root.dsk and restart. This way your old root disk remains saved until you are satisfied that new is working fine and you can delete the old one then. This process does take long though, I ran `sudo bash wubi-resize_1.5b.sh --max-override 100` overnight and it was done when I woke up in the morning, so don't know the exact time.