# Wubi uninstallation and partitions question

Tags: dual-boot, windows, wubi

I downloaded the wubi.exe file and before I install ubuntu, I want to make sure of some stuff first.

I have two hard drives in my computer `C:` (which have windows 7 on it) 950 GB  and `D:` which is empty and have 500 GB in it.

I'm wondering if when I choose the installation size 30 GB in wubi (which is maximum ) it will only take 30 GB from my `D` drive and won't affect the rest and the `C` drive and whenever i uninstall wubi from control panel (if I don't like ubuntu), will I get my 30 GB back and will the D drive be back as it was?

Comment: Answer is yes, you will get that space back

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, yes, it will only install on the D drive, and affect only the 30gb you allocated to it. Likewise, when uninstalled, I think that it *should* remove the virtual disk that Wubi installs to.

If you ever want to increase the amount of space allocated to Wubi (taken from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2465/is-it-possible-to-extend-the-disk-space-available-to-a-wubi-install/2467#2467)):

> ## How do I resize the virtual disks?
>
> You can use the
> following script to move /home to a
> dedicated virtual disk.
>
> Download wubi-add-virtual-disk, open a
> terminal and run:
>
> ```
> sudo sh wubi-add-virtual-disk /home 15000
> ```
>
> Where the first argument is the
> directory to move to a new dedicated
> disk, and the second argument is the
> size in MB.
>
> You should now reboot. If you are
> happy with the result, you can now
> remove /home.backup. To undo the
> changes remove /home, copy rename
> /home.backup to /home and remove the
> /home line in /etc/fstab.
>
> Note that contrary to previous
> information, this script is not
> suitable for moving /usr - experienced
> users may be able to do this manually,
> at own risk, following a process
> similar to that outlined in the file.
> (Do not rename /usr until the very
> last moment, as rsync is installed
> there.)

---

I haven't ever used Wubi, I've just done some reading up on it, so take my answer with a grain of salt.

Comment: LVPM hasn't worked on Wubi since release 8.04

Comment: @bcbc My bad, I took it from another post; fixed, and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you remove ubuntu(wubi) you will bet back your disk like it was.

Comment: but does it take more than 30 because my friend told me it makes a folder with the exact space in the hard drive ? and can i use the rest of my harddrive with wubi on it ?

Comment: first remove wubi normally after that you can delete all folder of it

Comment: if answer is okey . please confirm

Comment: Removing wubi will delete that folder too

Comment: @Tachyons yes i know and how can i say it ?

Comment: @JoeNofal WUBI will put a 30GB file in a folder in your second hard 500GB drive. The rest of the hard drive will be available to Windows as before. **Do not delete the files/folders created by WUBI while in Windows. This will make Ubuntu unbootable.** Within Ubuntu, the two drives and any partitions they may have will appear as icons in Nautilus (the equivalent of Windows Explorer). Clicking on those icons will make them accessible from within Ubuntu.

Comment: If you install on `D:`, then the `C:` drive will appear as an icon in Nautilus, whereas the `D:` drive will only be available under the directory /host