# How I increase Wubi Install to 100 Giga

Tags: wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to extend the disk space available to a wubi install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2465/is-it-possible-to-extend-the-disk-space-available-to-a-wubi-install)

I'm at 30giga Wubi installed. I want 100 giga. I'm sure one of you smart dudes have the answer, because Linux is where the really people are hanging out these days. Yep, I'm new to this. So please help.

Comment: See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_resize_the_virtual_disks.3F

Comment: I wouldn't create a 100GB `root.disk`. Wubi can access data from an `NTFS` partition fine with the benefit that you have easy read/write access from Windows as well, and it's not at risk if the `root.disk` gets corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its wise to make a 100Gb wubi install that's why they limit you to 30Gb . It can slow down the performance a lot. If you want a 100Gb install why dont you install it on another partition or perhaps shrink the drive and make a new partition and then instlal Ubuntu into it.