# Making Wubi bigger, or Upgrading to Ubuntu without loosing Windows?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, partitioning, wubi

I have 4 hard disks. I've got Wubi installed on one, and Windows installed on another.

The 300GB Drive for Wubi/Ubuntu is empty, except for Wubi. I'd like to let it take the full 300GB if it's appropriate, not the 30GB that Wubi gave it.

I still need Windows as software on the two "data" needs it and there isn't a Linux alternative yet, so dual booting is still required.

My Drives:
1TB Windows,
300GB Data,
1TB Data (Steam),
300GB Wubi

I'm very new to Linux, I think you may be able to blame Gabe Newell for this one.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2465/is-it-possible-to-extend-the-disk-space-available-to-a-wubi-install

Comment: You can either uninstall Wubi and reinstall from a live USB/CD or copy the root.disk and then migrate your Wubi back to the partition: http://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install

Answer (score 0):

You can do a normal install of ubuntu, safely, on the disk that now holds wubi.

Steps:

1. Uninstall wubi (maybe move your personal files to a data disk first);
2. Download a normal ubuntu installer;
3. Boot it from usb or cd;
4. The installation program will ask you for a target disk. Select the one where wubi was previously installed.