# How to migrate from Wubi to a regular installation?

Tags: windows, dual-boot, wubi, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert Wubi install into regular install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install)

I recently installed Ubuntu through Wubi and I love it enough that I am ready to ditch Windows! My set up is like this:

- Drive 1: 80 GB SSD Windows 7
- Drive 2: 320 GB HDD Ubuntu (installed through Wubi)
- Drive 3: 1000 TB NTFS media drive

What I want to do is move the Ubuntu installation from the 320 gig hard drive to my SSD and totally get rid of Windows. Would be great if I could preserve my current Ubuntu install during the process since it's finally working. :-)