# Is it possible to remove windows from hostmachine after installing Ubuntu 11.10 inside it?

Tags: windows

I have two questions

1. I installed Ubuntu 11.10 inside of Windows 7 on dual-boot using the Wubi installer. I believe I used the 2nd option of 'installing inside windows' with 'reduced disk performance'. Just wondering what the best way is to remove Windows and have those partitions available for use by Oneiric Ocelot.
2. Is it possible to change the boot menu options to have Ubuntu first. If so, how do I do this.

I'm open to good ideas.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Ubuntu rely on Windows if I install it using the Windows installer?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/143518/does-ubuntu-rely-on-windows-if-i-install-it-using-the-windows-installer)

Comment: You asked two question. Please separate this   question into two questions instead. First part is a duplicated of the question Eliah  Kagan posted.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ready to remove windows, probably the easiest thing to do would be to back up your data and do a fresh, standard install overwriting all your partitions.

Your other option would be to migrate your wubi install outside of windows and then delete windows.

migrating wubi has been discussed here : [How to migrate from Wubi to a regular installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27988/how-to-migrate-from-wubi-to-a-regular-installation)