# Does Ubuntu rely on Windows if I install it using the Windows installer?

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert Wubi install into regular install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install)

If I install Ubuntu to a new partition using the Windows installer (Wubi), will I be able to uninstall Windows, and have Ubuntu boot by itself? Or does it rely on Windows? If I uninstall windows will Ubuntu be useless?

But the reason I can't install Ubuntu using the CD is because of this problem: 
When I try to install the 64bit version of 12.04 through a CD, It just skips to the windows boot screen.

This user has the same problem as I just listed:
[Unable to install the 64-bit version of Ubuntu on both a Dell XPS 15z or a Dell XPS 8300.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141596/unable-to-install-the-64-bit-version-of-ubuntu-on-both-a-dell-xps-15z-or-a-dell)

Also I've followed the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD), but nothing has helped. I would like to use the 64bit installation, but sadly I cant.