# no kernel found at system startup

Tags: 10.10, boot, kernel, wubi

I'd installed `ubuntu10.10` in `windows7`. It was working well but now a days when I choose `ubuntu` at the start-up of the system it does not found any `kernel`.

Is there any way how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

- Have you upgraded or changed anything before it stopped working?
- Did you change the default boot partition?

Ubuntu will probably be looking in the wrong partition for the kernel.

**I will edit this answer as you respond.**

**EDIT:** This great answer **[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143518/does-ubuntu-rely-on-windows-if-i-install-it-using-the-windows-installer)** gives you more info on the WUBI installer. This could be part of the problem. Generally I wouldn't use the WUBI for anything other than to try Ubuntu. Anything goes wrong with your windows partition or install it can usually have serious problems with the Ubuntu install.

Comment: I'd not upgraded it. But I just wanted to connect it to another computer for LAN. But that was unsuccessful. After that I properly shut down the computer, but after that `ubuntu` is not starting. As I mentioned, I'd installed it in `windows`, it is installed in a separate partition.