# How do I remove windows on Ubuntu partition?

Tags: installation, wubi

I'm new to UBUNTU, I have an old PC and wanted to try it out. Installed it using the windows installer and it created its own partition. I would like to uninstall windows and run this as the sole OS. Can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Ubuntu rely on Windows if I install it using the Windows installer?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/143518/does-ubuntu-rely-on-windows-if-i-install-it-using-the-windows-installer)

Answer (score 2):

Since you installed Ubuntu using the WUBI, which means you did it from inside Windows it will be difficult (but possible) to have only Ubuntu. What I highly recommend for your case is just to burn the ISO image on a Pen Drive or CDROM/DVDROM and install it via the Standard Ubuntu installer (Booting from the CD/DVD/USB Drive). That way you can even choose to remove Windows if you want and have it only with Ubuntu.

You can also even repartition the hard drive to have a space for Ubuntu and a space for Windows.

Basically with the Ubuntu installer you have a little more freedom compared to WUBI. And to top it off, it is very easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you like Ubuntu you can burn the ubuntu .iso to a CD or put it on a flash driver and install it.

[Burn iso](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto)

[USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

When you install it, simply use the entire Hard drive (Erase disk and install Ubuntu). No need to uninstall Windows.

[image: Install image]

Alternately you can migrate your wubi install, but that will likely take more time and effort.

[migrate wubi](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi)