# How do I remove windows after installing Ubuntu 12.04 via WUBI

Tags: windows, wubi, delete

I'm about to install Ubuntu by using Wubi. Can I then delete Windows and keep Ubuntu?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Ubuntu rely on Windows if I install it using the Windows installer?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/143518/does-ubuntu-rely-on-windows-if-i-install-it-using-the-windows-installer)

Answer (score 5):

You **cannot remove Windows** after a WUBI installation.  WUBI installs as a folder ***INSIDE*** Windows so if you delete your Windows partition, you will delete your Wubi-Ubuntu as well.

If you want to remove Windows you have 2 options.

- Install Ubuntu as a dual boot and then after you know everything works you can remove your Windows.
- Install Ubuntu and during installation select the option that will install Ubuntu on the entire disk.  This will reformat the entire disk and wipe Windows in the process.

If you are sure that Ubuntu will work with your system then I would recommend the second one as it is less work, just make sure to save all your important files first.

If you are not sure if Ubuntu is for you, install as a Wubi system and try it, if it works on your computer and you want to wipe Windows you can either migrate your Wubi install or just do a Standard install (if you don't do alot of changes to your Wubi install, I would just do a clean install rather than migrate).

Comment: Just to add to this answer in Ubuntu you can easily figure out all programs that are installed and then copy them and install them once you do a fresh install and most settings are in your /home directory.

dpkg --get-selections > dpkg.list
apt-get update
dpkg --set-selections < dpkg.list
apt-get -u dselect-upgrade

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  The virtual partition that is running Ubuntu is coming from Windows.  You have to pop in your Ubuntu CD, reboot, then go through the installation process.  If you want to get rid of Windows, select the option to replace Windows with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You need to boot on your Ubuntu cd, dvd or USB key in order to get the option to replace Windows by Ubuntu. To do this, you may have to change the boot order settings in your Bios.

Answer (score 0):

To remove windows and install ubuntu, you need to do the following:

- Enter the BIOS setup(when the computer turns on, press del key)
- Change the boot sequence so that CD/DVD is you primary boot device.(Every BIOS is different, look inside *advanced bios settings* if your machine is old and you are unable to find it)
- Save and exit
- When the computer restarts, Ubuntu setup should start
- Select **REPLACE WINDOWS WITH UBUNTU**(on everything else click next, and I recommend to select *install updates* and *install third-party software*)
- You can customize the installation, but these are the recommended settings