# How to delete windows, after installing ubuntu via windows installer?

Tags: installation, windows, delete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove windows after installing Ubuntu 12.04 via WUBI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161335/how-do-i-remove-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-12-04-via-wubi)

How can Io delete windows, after installing ubuntu via the windows installer?

Comment: Please see [How do I remove windows after installing Ubuntu 12.04 via WUBI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/161335/how-do-i-remove-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-12-04-via-wubi)

Comment: Someone flagged it as Off-topic , i vouch it as duplicate though.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to move the Wubi installation to a new partition, then you can remove Windows.

See the Wubi migration guide:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi