# Will removing Windows also remove Wubi?

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Ubuntu rely on Windows if I install it using the Windows installer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143518/does-ubuntu-rely-on-windows-if-i-install-it-using-the-windows-installer)

I installed Ubuntu via Ubuntu Windows Installer 12.04, but now I want to remove Windows on my computer. Will Ubuntu be removed, If I remove windows?

I also want to change storage size, because Ubuntu is really running slower than Windows 7.

Comment: If you installed via WUBI , then YES , you cannot access Ubuntu. Going with a fresh Install of Ubuntu replacing Windows would be better option.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you installed Ubuntu on the same partition of Windows, you'll probably lose Ubuntu since you'll format that partition to remove Windows. Else if Ubuntu is installed to a different partition then probably nothing will happen. To change storage size you could use software to do that such as rescue disc, erd, etc.

Comment: Even though ubuntu is install on another partition it would remain untouched if windows is removed but he wont able to boot to ubuntu as windows bootmgr will be removed when windows is replaced with something else.

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to install a fresh copy of Ubuntu physically on different partition of same disk, leaving Windows 7 untouched if you want to use Windows 7 and Ubuntu as a dual boot.

To dual boot:

1. Remove Ubuntu Wubi from Windows 7 using uninstaller within Windows 7 (in control center)
2. Reboot the machine once Wubi is removed from Windows 7
3. Install fresh copy using Ubuntu LiveCd

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**.

- If you installed Wubi (Ubuntu Windows Installer) on Drive C, it will be removed.
- If you installed Wubi on another drive, the data will be there but you will no longer be able to boot it because removing Windows also removes its boot manager which is necessary to start Wubi.
- The best option to address the "slowness" is to install Ubuntu via a Live-CD or Live-USB as a true dual-boot
- You can **convert** your Wubi to a "regular" install with the [**MigrateWubi** script](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi) (which has the blessings of the official Wubi Community Wiki). Note that you will need to run this from either a Live-CD/Live-USB OR another Linux installation.

Comment: Is there any way to transfer the Wubi image into a separate partition, in preparation for removing Windows (or transferring an existing Ubuntu installation from Wubi to a regular partition without a reinstall)?

Comment: @neon_overload Converting a Wubi installation to a "regular" (i.e. on a regular partition) has recently become easier with the MigrateWubi script (which has the blessings of the official Wubi Community Wiki). [See here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi)

Answer (score 1):

When you install Ubuntu via Wubi, it creates a very large file to hold all those Ubuntu stuff.  The whole file acts like a virtual disk.  It is based on Windows, so if you remove Windows, Ubuntu will also be removed.

To have only Ubuntu on your computer, you will have to have a full install (instead of Wubi) of ubuntu on your computer.

You can have 2 options: Remove Wubi and do a clean installation of Ubuntu or Migrate Wubi to another partition(which, in other words, upgrade a wubi install to a full Ubuntu installation).

The first one is quite simple.  Find "Ubuntu" in the "Change or Modify Windows Programs" panel in Windows.  Right-Click and select "Remove".  Then, install Ubuntu from a Ubuntu CD or DVD.  **Note that all the stuff in Wubi will be deleted.**

If you want to keep the settings and files in Wubi, you can migrate the Wubi install to another partition.  I personally don't recommend that, since a wrong step can render your computer unbootable.  Read [the UbuntuForums guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1519354) or [the Ubuntu Wiki Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi#Automatic_migration) for the steps.  After that, you can remove Windows with [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on/143482#143482)

And Wubi can be slower than a Full Ubuntu installation, because it is based on Windows instead of standing on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are re-installing windows, **And you DO NOT select "format disk"**
-> Then no, wubi will not be deleted.

Wubi+Ubuntu is a big file on the C:\ drive that pretends to be a hard drive. Reinstalling windows will only move USER files and C:\windows to a "windows.old" folder.

But if you mean to delete the drive completely, no.

**Remember-> If it asks you to format, Say-> NO"**
Unless that's what you want.