# Installed Ubuntu with WUBI, how can I completely remove Windows Vista?

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall, system, windows-vista

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04.1 yesterday, and I'm happy with how it's working. I think I installed it as a dual system though, because Ubuntu and Vista shows up when the system boots up.

I installed Ubuntu using WUBI. I do not want Vista on my computer anymore. Is there a way to delete it without corrupting my laptop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Ubuntu rely on Windows if I install it using the Windows installer?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/143518/does-ubuntu-rely-on-windows-if-i-install-it-using-the-windows-installer)

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete Vista right now because you installed it using wubi.

If you want to keep only Ubuntu, you will have to reinstall Ubuntu.

First make a bootable disk or USB.
Then boot from that. And select **erase Vista** when choosing installation option.

Answer (score 1):

If I were in your shoes, I would back up the files I would want to keep, and then I would proceed with a full installation of Ubuntu.

This time though, you should **not** use WUBI. Make sure you have a bootable Ubuntu Disk, or a bootable USB flash drive (you can make one with [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)). Then make sure you follow the guide available [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu/152902#152902) and opt to format the hard drive when given the choice.

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to Ubuntu.

As pointed in [Deepak's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/192600/58928) you have to reinstall the system in order to completely erase MS Vista.

All the guided steps to download, burn, and install can be found at [Ubuntu web site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/try-ubuntu-before-you-install). And here you have the guide to burn the image into a USB from [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) and from [Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)