# I installed Ubuntu using Wubi. Can I now uninstall Windows XP and keep Ubuntu?

Tags: uninstall

I have installed Ubuntu using the Windows installer. Now I want to uninstall Windows XP, and keep Ubuntu. How do I do that, please?

Comment: "I have installed Ubuntu using windows installer, now I want to uninstall Windows XP, how do I do that, please?" - What you're asking is impossible to do, if you installed Ubuntu using Wubi, Ubuntu will be removed if you remove XP, so to remove Windows  properly, boot a LiveCD and then remove the partitions. Then proceed to install Ubuntu on a partition.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/192596/installed-ubuntu-with-wubi-how-can-i-completely-remove-windows-vista

Answer (score 1):

When you install Ubuntu with Wubi, it resides within a file in the Windows system. So if you delete the Windows installation the Ubuntu installation is also lost. You cannot simply delete Windows and continue to use Ubuntu.