# Uninstall Windows after Installing Ubuntu WITH Windows?

Tags: windows, wubi, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Ubuntu rely on Windows if I install it using the Windows installer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143518/does-ubuntu-rely-on-windows-if-i-install-it-using-the-windows-installer)

Would it be possible to somehow uninstall Windows after installing Ubuntu with wubi.exe? So I install Ubuntu using Windows, but then REMOVE Windows and add GRUB so the computer boots up TO ONLY Ubuntu afterwards? I am having a hard time with using USB or CD's, and wubi seems to be the easiest method. Any help is appreciated:)