# Migrating wubi to a real partition

Tags: 11.10, partitioning, dual-boot, windows-7, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert Wubi install into regular install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install)

I have three partitions,

`/dev/sda1`
**File System:** NTFS
**Mount Point:** /media/System Reserved
**Size:** 100 MiB
**Free:** 42.88 MiB
**Flags:** boot
I assume this to be the Windows boot loader

`/dev/sda2`
**File System:** NTFS
**Mount Point:** /media/6A1032D21032A54B
**Size:** 146.39 GiB
**Free:** 95.11 GiB
**Flags:**
Which contains the Windows 7 Installation

`/dev/sda3`
**File System:** NTFS
**Mount Point:** /host
**Size:** 319.28 GiB
**Free:** 289.18 GiB
**Flags:**
Which contains **only** the 30 GiB Wubi install of Ubuntu.

What I want to do is,

- shrink Windows to be only 100 GiB
- Add the extra space onto `/dev/sda3`
- Take some of that extra space and use it to create `Swap Space`
- Take the 30GiB Wubi install and put it onto `/dev/sda3` using the entire space.
- Have a still functioning Ubuntu and Windows.

I am looking at using [This Forum Post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1519354) which uses `wubi-move-2.1.sh`

So my questions are:
if I was to use: `sudo bash wubi-move-2.1.sh /dev/sda3` would that work or fail as it is the same partition as the virtual disk is on?

Obviously that would create it without swap as well,
Would I be safe to in Gparted from the Wubi Install resize `/dev/sda1` and create `/dev/sda4` as swap? or would that kill my windows 7 Install?

If I did as mentioned above, could I resize `/dev/sda3` from Gparted from within the Wubi install as it is the partition with the virtual disk for Wubi?

With the assumption of nothing going wrong with the above, or of course booting off the live ubuntu cd would this procedure work:

- In gParted:

  - Resize `/dev/sda2` to 100.00 GiB
  - Resize `/dev/sda3` to 355.67 GiB
  - Create `/dev/sda4` with 10GiB (I have 4GB Ram)
- Run `sudo bash wubi-move-2.1.sh /dev/sda3 /dev/sda4`
  or  `sudo bash wubi-move-2.1.sh --root-disk=/media/whatever_mounted_as/root.disk /dev/sda3 /dev/sda4` if run from live CD