# How to migrate Wubi install to a new partition

Tags: 11.10, partitioning, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert Wubi install into regular install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install)

Sorry if this has being asked before.
I have 2 partitions one is my Windows install the other is blank.
I installed Ubuntu 11.10 into virtual disc on my Windows partition as kind of a test run.
How do I move it to a new partition?

Comment: You're right, this has been asked before (but it's not always easy to find things). My answer is here: http://askubuntu.com/a/36904/14916 but you can also use the accepted answer to do it manually (don't use LVPM).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure, but I believe this was asked on the Ubuntu forums, too. As far as I could tell from the responses, this is not quite possible. What you can do, however, is copy your /home/user (where "user" is your username) to your Windows partition and install a fresh Ubuntu alongside Windows. Then copy the contents back from the Windows partition and you'll have an Ubuntu install that is almost identical to your wubi install. The only things you will notice that are lacking are the programs you had installed. You can re-install these and they will have exactly the same configuration as before.