# Wubi Device /dev/loop0 full. How to get more space?

Tags: 12.04, wubi, filesystem

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0       17G   15G  838M  95% /
udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           762M  928K  761M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G  940K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda5       196G   18G  178G   9% /host
/dev/mmcblk0p1  7.4G  365M  7.1G   5% /media/3064-6365
/dev/sdb1       961M  157M  805M  17% /media/44C7-E9E7
/dev/sdc1       932G  8.4G  924G   1% /media/My Book
/dev/sda2       100M   25M   76M  25% /media/SYSTEM RESERVED
/dev/sda3       240G   42G  199G  18% /media/Gateway
owner@ubuntu:~$
```

Above is terminal output. I realize that I can not down load files because of the low space on `/dev/loop0`. But, I do not know how to fix. Would like to use part of `/dev/sda5`, and `/dev/sda3` is Windows 7; `/dev/sdc1` is an ext. HD.

Comment: You should add a small description of what you have running there, especially details about the loop partition. The output of `sudo losetup -a` would certainly be helpful.

Comment: $ sudo losetup -a
[sudo] password for owner: 
/dev/loop0: [0805]:81 (/host/ubuntu/disks/root.disk)
$                                                                   By the way what does this do?

Comment: There's a similar question at http://askubuntu.com/questions/2465/is-it-possible-to-extend-the-disk-space-available-to-a-wubi-install but comments say that newer information is available at various links.

Comment: Ran: 
sudo apt-get autoremove 
sudo apt-get autoclean 
gksu baobab 
This gave me:
$ df -h 
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
/dev/loop0 17G 13G 3.1G 81% / 
...(skip others) 
owner@ubuntu:~$ 

So, I gained 20%, I would like to gain another 60% by moving thing to other locations. I was not sure where to start with wubi  , however I now know that it was installed because of the comments with the above commands. But, I did not know what to do still. I then read the comments from John S. Gruber.

Comment: owner@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0       30G   13G   16G  45% /
udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           762M  924K  761M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G  888K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda5       196G   48G  149G  25% /host
/dev/mmcblk0p1  7.4G  366M  7.1G   5% /media/3064-6365
/dev/sdb1       961M  157M  805M  17% /media/44C7-E9E7
/dev/sdc1       932G   12G  920G   2% /media/My Book
owner@ubuntu:~$

Comment: The above was after resizing to 32G using the resizing the space availiable ... link. While 45% is not 20%, it is still better than 100% full. Thanks John S. Gruber.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are running Ubuntu with wubi. Is that true?

If so, please refer to [How can I check how much space there is left on WUBI versus how much space it takes on my HDD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107470/how-can-i-check-how-much-space-there-is-left-on-wubi-versus-how-much-space-it-ta) for information about what you can do when you are short on space.

There's a link on that question to the wubi guide [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide).

For resizing the space available you should refer to [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk).

Comment: wubi not sure. How to check for it?

Comment: I went to the "How can I check how..." page, Ran: sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get autoclean and Ran: gksu baobab and the other commmand line commands.

Comment: Were you able to free up some space? re: wubi. It doesn't look like you booted from an Ubuntu Live CD or memory stick to install Ubuntu. Did you install Ubuntu by downloading and executing the wubi program to install Ubuntu while executing Windows?

Comment: This gave me $ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0       17G   13G  3.1G  81% /
...(skip others) owner@ubuntu:~$  So, I gained 20%, I would like to gain another 60% by moving thing to other locations. I am not sure where to start with wubi and I now know that it was installed because of the comments with the above commands. But, I do not know what to do still.

Comment: I've added a couple of links to my answer that may help. It would be best if you could mention what you have now done to your queston along with the new size numbers.

Comment: I've added the wubi tag to the question so someone more familiar with wubi than me can provide a more confident, self-contained, and therefore much better answer than this one.

Comment: By the way, I am seeing that wubi works with version prior to 12.04, but does not say anything with 12.04. Is there a new way or updated version of doing this?

Comment: "It would be best if you could mention what you have now done to your queston along with the new size numbers." I am not sure how to answer this. And, thanks for the links and tag add-ons.

Comment: I was trying to say that it would be a good idea for you to edit your question, adding what you did to save space, that you would like to save more and adding the output you put in your comment above. You can click on "edit" under your question to add or change information or wording, etc.