# UBUNTU 12.04 installed on a 50GB partition, I've used 18, and Im told I am full. help?

Tags: partitioning, storage

I noticed a problem trying to install software with both `sudo apt-get` (etc.) and the software center, and after using

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

I am returned `dpkg: error: failed to write status database record about 'empathy-common' to '/var/lib/dpkg/status': No space left on device` so I try

```
df -h
```

[image]

Be forewarned, I'm a complete Linux noob, so I'm sorry if this is a face-palm kind of question.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT1: [image: Here you go @kingmilo]

EDIT2: Thanks for all you're help guys! It's been so long since I installed Ubuntu that I completely forgot I used Wubi. looking at it again, I can see that it defaults to giving Ubuntu only 17 GB. I can see now that I ignored that setting. I am currently reinstalling Ubuntu with a larger... group(?).

Comment: Could you paste the results of `df -ih`

Comment: Have a look at these threads: http://askubuntu.com/questions/211693/why-is-my-dev-loop0-showing-full and http://askubuntu.com/questions/173691/wubi-device-dev-loop0-full-how-to-get-more-space

Answer (score 1):

Because you did not install Ubuntu into a 50 gb partition; you installed it with Wubi into a 17 gb file inside your Windows partition.

Answer (score 0):

According to your [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBahU.png), your partition is indeed full. Ubuntu is installed on `/` so I guess you were looking at the wrong entry...

I guess you have to remove some stuff to free up your partition or try to resize it (but that is a bit tricky...)