# disk space lacking

Tags: 12.04, server, partitioning, disk-usage

My Ubuntu partition was working on 50gb . However, even-though I had not used much of the memory, I was still getting messages saying the disk space is low. I increased the partition, but am still getting that error. I hardly have any bulky programs or anything like that installed. Where did the disk space go? Can someone please have a look and tell me what is happening?

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0       19G   17G  1.6G  92% /
udev            982M  4.0K  982M   1% /dev
tmpfs           396M  1.2M  395M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            990M  384K  989M   1% /run/shm
none            100M   36K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda3       138G   25G  114G  18% /host
```

Comment: Where is the image?

Comment: sorry it wasnt letting me post the image!

Comment: Your Ubuntu (Wubi) partition is not 50GB, it is 19GB and you are using 17GB of it. See this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/107470/how-can-i-check-how-much-space-there-is-left-on-wubi-versus-how-much-space-it-ta

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Disk Usage Analyzer, baobab in 12.04, to see where the disk usage has gone. If you are using the command line only, there's a number of ways to [find the largest directory in Linux](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=linux%20find%20largest%20directory&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gl=uk&redir_esc=&ei=NSabUYWTEu-S0AWp7ICoBQ)

Thinks you can keep an eye on include:

- Log files (/var/log)
- apt cache (/var/cache/apt/archives)

Comment: In addition, on a desktop, `.xsession-errors` can grow really large, when you have display-problems.

Comment: the system was installed using wubi.. could it be that it messed up the spacing allocation or something??