# Running out of space on a Wubi install with a non-functional Windows OS

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, wubi

My Ubuntu installed through Wubi is running out of space: I have about 4 GB free.

If I partition the part of my hard drive that has Windows on it, will I lose Ubuntu? I'm fairly sure I will and if so, is there any way I could burn a copy of Ubuntu OS onto a CD?

Note, my Windows 7 OS is not able to run so I can't go into it to get anything out. The moment I try to boot into Windows my computer crashes, which is why I'm switching over to Ubuntu. Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can partition the drive and it shouldn't matter unless you change both the `UUID` and the partition number that contains the Wubi install.

But if you want to replace Windows with Ubuntu, then it makes sense to buy an external hard drive, backup all your data and then either [migrate the Wubi install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install) back to the hard drive, or install a fresh copy of Ubuntu over the entire drive and then copy your data back.

I like to migrate my Ubuntu installs, because setting it up from brand new is a pain. But for many people, fresh installs are common. You can choose whatever you prefer.

If you're not sure what to do just yet, you can probably also try [resizing the Wubi install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk) as a temporary measure or [freeing up space](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107470/how-can-i-check-how-much-space-there-is-left-on-wubi-versus-how-much-space-it-ta).