# How to increase the disk space of Ubuntu 13.04 installed besides Windows 7

Tags: 13.04, partitioning, system-installation, wubi

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 besides Windows 7 with initial space allocated as 18.2 GB. Now I get a warning to increase the disk space and I wanted to increase the disk space for Ubuntu. My total hard disk space is 320 GB and as seen from other posts, when I execute the following command in the terminal :

> sudo fdisk -l

I receive the following response

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xcfc64c27

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     3074047     1536000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         3074048   596467711   296696832    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       596467712   625139711    14336000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

[image]

I ran `df` command and got he below response :

```
xxx@ubuntu:~$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0      17753424 14090256   2754676  84% /
none                   4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             1861852        8   1861844   1% /dev
tmpfs             374280      900    373380   1% /run
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             1871396      156   1871240   1% /run/shm
none              102400       28    102372   1% /run/user
/dev/sda2      296696828 58764616 237932212  20% /host
```

It seems like installed in /dev/loop0 but not showing up in Gparted.

Please help me increase the disk space for Ubuntu 13.04. 
Note : I coudn't see any GParted disk partitioner to make use of as observed in other threads.

Comment: Install gparted on your ubuntu,take a screenshot of gparted,upload it to `imgur` and provide the link.You must need gparted live disk to resize your partition.

Comment: http://imgur.com/iFXgfn3

Comment: In which partition did you installed ubuntu?

Comment: `xxx@ubuntu:~$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0      17753424 14090256   2754676  84% /
none                   4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             1861852        8   1861844   1% /dev
tmpfs             374280      900    373380   1% /run
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             1871396      156   1871240   1% /run/shm
none              102400       28    102372   1% /run/user
/dev/sda2      296696828 58764616 237932212  20% /host`
It seems like installed in /dev/loop0 but not showing in Gparted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Wubi, that's why a linux filesystem is not apparent.

There are a couple of methods for resizing Wubi.

This has to be run from within a live environment.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeWubiDisk

You can also use a slightly different method

The first method here can be used from within the wubi environment

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk#Automated_resize

The second method here needs to run from a live environment

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk#Manual_resize

Also see here [How do I give Ubuntu more space (when installed inside Windows 7 (via wubi))?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35401/how-do-i-give-ubuntu-more-space-when-installed-inside-windows-7-via-wubi)

Comment: Can I resize to 100 GB (and I have enough 100 GB unused space), but when I give the command as : `sudo bash wubi-resize.sh 100` I get a warning as : `wubi-resize.sh: The new disk cannot exceed 32 GB unless the
wubi-resize.sh: --max-override option is used (not recommended).`

Is it advisable to resize it to 100 GB?

Comment: I'd not see the point tbh - you can access the windows space afaik through /hosts. My normal ubuntu installs rarely get above 10Gb - but I do store data elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You installed ubuntu through **wubi**.
For resizing the space allocated for ubuntu installed through wubi,you must refer [**this**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk).

And also refer to   [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107470/how-can-i-check-how-much-space-there-is-left-on-wubi-versus-how-much-space-it-ta) to know how much of space did wubi takes from the HDD.