# root directory almost full but still lots of free space on the partition

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, mount, directory, root

some time ago I installed 12.04 from windows xp on a separate "linux" partition via wubi. this partition was allocated 50 GB. my problem now is that obviously the root directory does not have access to the entire volume but only to about 10 gigs which is now not very far from being exhausted.

when I call partition monitor I get this:

the hard drive is divided into 3 partitions altogether: the windows volume (sda1) with 146 gigs, a "save" volume (sda6) for backups and stuff with some 103 gigs and the linux volume (sda5) with about 50 gigs of space however being host of this strange subdivision "loop0" where the root directory seems to be placed (so this 10 gigs of the loop0 division seem to belong to the sda5 partition, at least thats what I get)

my question is: how can I make the ubuntu root directory to have access to the full 50 gigs of the partition instead of being restricted to the loop0 subdivision

to give you some more info heres what the df and mount comments tell me:

```
knabbits@ubuntu:~$ df -h
df: `/root/.gvfs': Permission denied
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0       11G  7.5G  2.3G  78% /
udev            2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           400M 1004K  399M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G  492K  2.0G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda5        49G   12G   38G  24% /host
/dev/sda1       147G  116G   32G  79% /media/Windows
/dev/sda6       103G   86G   18G  84% /media/save


knabbits@ubuntu:~$ mount
/dev/loop0 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/sda5 on /host type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda1 on /media/Windows type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda6 on /media/save type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/knabbits/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=knabbits)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /root/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev)
```

as you can notice I yet dont know much bout linux file structure but still thats the issues that make you want to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107470/how-can-i-check-how-much-space-there-is-left-on-wubi-versus-how-much-space-it-ta) about how to free up space in your /dev/loop0 partition. Then, consider [migrating your WUBI install to an ordinary system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install).