# Regular installation from Wubi

Tags: installation, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert Wubi install into regular install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install)

I have Ubuntu installed on my D drive using Wubi. There are some other files on D drive. Win 7 is installed on C drive. What would be the best way to make regular installation of Ubuntu? On D or C drive? Do I have to make a partition?

```
Disk /dev/sda: 640.1 GB, 640133946880 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 77825 cylinders, total 1250261615 sectors 
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
Disk identifier: 0x58fd0634 

Device     Boot       Start          End      Blocks    Id   System 
/dev/sda1    *         2048       206847      102400     7   HPFS/NTFS/exFAT 
/dev/sda2            206848   1045460991   522627072     7   HPFS/NTFS/exFAT 
/dev/sda3        1045460992   1250258943   102398976     7   HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: Please edit your answer with the output `sudo fdisk -l` (that's a lower case -L). You will have to make a partition, you cannot install on `C:` or `D:`

Comment: Disk /dev/sda: 640.1 GB, 640133946880 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 77825 cylinders, total 1250261615 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x58fd0634

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848  1045460991   522627072    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3      1045460992  1250258943   102398976    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will have to create at least 1 partition to install Ubuntu. You can shrink either `/dev/sda2` or `/dev/sda3` to make space for Ubuntu. You can use the Windows 7 disk management console to do this (recommended) or GParted (I recommend that you have a Windows Repair CD handy in this case).

Then you can create an extended partition in the free space, and - using GParted either from the Wubi install or a live CD - create two logical partitions, one as `ext4` for Ubuntu and another as `linux-swap` for the swap partition. The swap partition must be > than the size of your RAM if you want to be able to hibernate. Refer to [this guide](http://members.iinet.net.au/~herman546/p22.html) for an indepth discussion of partitioning using GParted on a live CD.

Then you can either migrate the Ubuntu install using the link Jorge Castro provided. There is a script that will do it automatically (my answer at that link) or you can do it manually as per the accepted answer.