# Can I reinstall and keep updates and software from my wubi installation?

Tags: wubi, swap, offline

I already have Ubuntu 11.10 which I installed it using 'wubi'. Now I noticed that this kind of installation have some limitation like I can't hibernate and etc.

Now I want to reinstall my Ubuntu from boot so I can have swap drive. But I already installed a lot of softwares from software center and also updated my Ubuntu.

Is there any way I could install this softwares offline?  I don't wanna download them again with my low speed internet :-(

Comment: See this: http://askubuntu.com/a/36904/14916 - it's not the accepted answer on that question, but it links to a Howto and script that can transfer the wubi install to partition (no loss/reinstall/download required). It also sets up hibernation provided you supply a swap partition (> size of RAM) to the script.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need a swap partition, you could resize your existing partition, create a new swap partition and add that to your installation's `/etc/fstab`. There is only a limited chance that things might go wrong (so back up!!) but it's fairly quick and painless.

1. Back up anything you can't easily replace.
2. Boot into a LiveCD or LiveUSB. This can be downloaded from Ubuntu.com - You've already installed once so you should be familiar with the process. Select "Try Ubuntu" when asked.
3. Load up GParted Partition Editor
4. Select your partition, right click it and click Resize. Resize it down to give you enough space for the new swap partition. How much of that largely depends on how much RAM you have. You need *at least* as much swap as you have RAM but most people say 1.5x is safer so if you have 4GB of RAM, you probably want 6GB of swap.
5. In the space at the end of the disk, right click and create a new partition. Set its format to `linux-swap` and click add.
6. Click the big green Tick and it will shrink your disk and create the new partition. When you're done there, reboot to your normal system.
7. Now you need the UUID of the new swap partition. You can see all the UUIDs by running `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid` in a terminal and you're looking for something like `a2d579b4-6ecd-1111-a612-2d11adbd11aa`. If you have a lot of disks you might need to run Disk Utility to work out which is which.
8. In a terminal run `sudoedit /etc/fstab` and add something like the following line:

   ```
   UUID=a2d579b4-6ecd-1111-a612-2d11adbd11aa none    swap    sw     0       0
   ```

   Though you want to replace the UUID with *your* swap partition's UUID from Step 7.
9. You can either reboot or run `sudo mount -a && sudo swapon -a` and you should have mounted swap space. Hurray!

Comment: for new user often it is a way to kill partition, even if it is paranoia )
nice method

Answer (score 0):

- First make full backup of your home directory into other drive or safe media.
- Then clean install your new Ubuntu distribution.
- Restore your home directory.
- ***Don't worry about software*** - just install it again later - so you will have fresh copy of software for your new Ubuntu distribution.
  To read: [*Ubuntu Community Documentation > Installing Software*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware)
- ***I do not recommend*** you to install software "offline". Just because it uncomfortable for new user, and can decrease security of your system.

*However,* you can try safe methods *offline installing* described here:
[**5.** *Installing packages without an Internet connection*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#Installing_packages_without_an_Internet_connection)

Also look this good answered question:
[*How can I install software offline?*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-offline)

Enjoy **Ubuntu**!