# How to change from Ubuntu Dual Boot to a Single Ubuntu Boot(Used Wubi Installer for Windows)

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert Wubi install into regular install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install)

I am quite new to Ubuntu and I would like to know how to change from a ubuntu-windows dual boot to a single boot of ubuntu. I would also like to increase the space in the ubuntu partition. Please explain this in easy to understand steps, as I am new to ubuntu.

Comment: From the WubiGuide: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_migrate_to_a_real_partition.2C_and.2BAC8-or_get_rid_of_Windows_entirely.3F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *can* be done (as the various available duplicates will point out) but unless there's been a major development that I haven't yet seen, it's definitely not something for a beginner.

I would suggest a new install from CD/USB alongside your existing Windows installation (proper dual-boot, not Wubi) and after you've copied out all the files you want to keep, you can minimise the space Windows takes up or get rid of it altogether.

I say this for two reasons:

- Installing Ubuntu from scratch takes very little time and has less chance to mess everything up.
- Converting the Wubi soft-partition to a real one and installing a bootloader (which you'll have to if you migrate your Wubi install) is very technical and takes a long time in itself.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly, you can not do this because you have a WUBI installation of ubuntu. 
What this means is that:

- WUBI installation depends on Windows OS existence
- WUBI installation of Ubuntu is just like a software installation in windows
- WUBI installation of Ubuntu is made in a big file inside windows

For a single Ubuntu boot you will need:

- Backup your files (in external hard disk)
- Download Ubuntu 11.10
- Burn it on a CD or USB
- Boot from CD or USB
- Select in installation mode "Remove Windows and install only Ubuntu"
  The link here is self explanatory : http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download 
  Just follow the 4 steps