# How to create a windows to Ubuntu partition file

Tags: dual-boot, boot-partition

I recently downloaded Ubuntu and running it as a dual-boot along side my Windows vista OS. I like Ubuntu very much and it is just what I'm looking for in an operating system, but, I can't seem to acquire any of my Windows docs, itunes, and other such things I have collected through the years which I want to switch over and use in Ubuntu. I was wondering how a partition file works and how to set one up; would I be able to directly use the doc and mp3 files and movies and such in Ubuntu with this partition file?

Basically I want to switch everything I have that is collected in my Windows to my new Ubuntu and need help establishing that.

-Thanks guys

Comment: Did you install the dual boot via an ISO on CD or flash drive, or did you install it using WUBI?

Comment: I installed it using WUBI

Answer (score 1):

Windows and Ubuntu uses diffent filesystems. Windows uses NTFS and Ubuntu uses propably EXT4. Fromout Ubuntu you can reach you files on the windows partition in Nautilus.

On this image [image: here] on the left panel of Nautilus you see 2 other filesystems. The one with labels `84 GB Filesystem` and the one with `179 GB filesystem`. Those filesystems represents other partitions. The one on your system will represent the Windows filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Because WUBI installs into a container file on the existing NTFS filesystem it is completely different than just trying to access another partition in a traditional dual boot situation.  If you a sure you like Ubuntu, and are ready to use it on a regular basis I would suggest removing the WUBI install (after saving anything you have created inside Ubuntu to a flash drive) then creating a true dual boot from a normal install ISO on CD or flash drive.  There is a reference to this in [How to convert Wubi install into regular install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install) (Note however my answer does not suggest migrating the install, I suggest removing it and reinstalling non-WUBI).  The normal install will preserve the windows boot, and when you are in Ubuntu you will have full access to the NTFS partition.  If I remember correctly it even asks if you want to migrate data though I have never done so.

I have a few computers running in this fashion because the all came with Windows, so I just shrink the Windows partition and leave it there, though I haven't booted into it in quite some time.  WUBI is a great way to test a computer, but isn't a long term solution and I have had several problems when trying to do distribution upgrades. So if you like it, jump in to a regular dual boot.

Comment: I think I'm ready to make the switch most definitely. I would have to restart back into windows and remove wubi then download the true duel boot? Before I do this I should most likely back my computer up on a disc to be safe from data loss? or should it be safe enough to go for it?

Comment: Always back up important data!  I have never had a problem and don't want to make it sound risky, but you should have a current backup of user data anyway, and especially before trying something new.  After you use the Windows uninstaller to remove WUBI and reboot to Windows to make sure everything is OK here is what I do. Because I want a computer that is almost totally committed to Ubuntu, I use the live boot and Gparted to manually shrink the Windows partition to a minimum size. I then boot in Windows to left disk check fix the resized partition, then normally install Ubuntu in free space.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free driver for a ext2/etx3 partition for Windows wich would enable easy file exchange between Windows and Linux.

http://www.fs-driver.org/

Comment: Not recommended: See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/