# Backup, install and restore Programms/Settings of Ubuntu (Wubi ) Installation

Tags: installation, partitioning, wubi, backup, settings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert Wubi install into regular install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install)

I would like to now how to backup my Ubuntu (Wubi) instllation correctly. I would like to install Ubuntu on my harddisk and replace my programms/files/settings from my previous wubi installation.

Is that somehow possible?

Thanks
Stefan