# Is it possible to copy Wubi install to another computer?

Tags: windows, wubi

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux overall. I am using Ubuntu on dual boot in my Dell netbook.
I installed Wubi yesterday and did lots of customizing and installing things.

I have a desktop with no OS in it. I wanted to make it Ubuntu. But I can't go through all the trouble and terminal and stuff. So I was wondering is there a way to copy my whole Ubuntu system (OS and all apps and files) and install them on my desktop? (so I have everything like I did on my netbook?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert Wubi install into regular install?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install) see also the links in the answers.

Comment: Almost but not quite Takkat - they'd still need to move the install to the other machine.

Answer (score 1):

## yup

1 . Install wubi in new pc

2 . Replace the ubuntu folder in the c:\ drive with ubuntu folder in the previous wubi installation

If it wont work backup the data and packages using aptoncd ,install fresh wubi , :)

Answer (score 0):

You could migrate wubi to a real partition - as it stands it's a file within windows.

Then clone that, seems like a lot of work given than the install is fairly short.

You could make backups of system files you have edited and copy them to the new install.

You could copy specific files from your /home folder to the new system - that is where all your personal configurations are.

If you copy your .bash_history file it will at least show you waht you had done in the wubi install.

Edit -

You can in fact access the wubi files from a livecd.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_can_I_access_my_Wubi_install_and_repair_my_install_if_it_won.27t_boot.3F

Comment: sounds like alot of work to copy a bunch of apps and flash :/ guess i should do a clean install and redo everything i did :< oh will thanks for the great help and fast response :) i hope with time i can completely throw away windows :D

Comment: The reason it sounds a lot of work is starting from wubi - otherwise it would be not long at all ;) I can do a clean install and copy the things I want in less than an hour.

Comment: i'll just try unetbootin to make a live usb and install it using that :) thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can boot your PC with the linux live cd or USB stick and then you will be easily able to install it in Graphical Interface mode. Or if you want to get a complete copy of the ubuntu system then you can use clonning. It is better explained in  http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/2-methods-to-clone-your-linux-hard-drive/

Comment: thanks :) i think i will do the live usb method as my netbook doesn't have an optical drive :)