# Help with migrating WUBI to it's own partition

Tags: partitioning, dual-boot, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert Wubi install into regular install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install)

Ok i really need help now. I've began building android from source code, but i'm using a wubi installation. And sadly, 30 GB isn't eve enough space for the first build. So, i want to migrate so i can expand my space to 50 GB. How can i expand my disk space once i migrate? Excuse me if this has been a past question. Oh yeah, I forgot to add, i want to dual boot windows 7 and ubuntu. And help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi

However, if you haven't done a lot of customizations in your wubi installation, I would just make a fresh install on a new partition, and then copy data from your home directory.

Also, don't skimp on disk space - 50Gb for building a huge codebase? What is it, year 2001? :)