# Install Ubuntu on a new partition?

Tags: partitioning, wubi

I have install Ubuntu with WUBI, but it uses a virtual disk how can I make it so Ubuntu uses a new partition instead of the virtual disk on my C: drive?

I have been googling for a few hours now, and I can't seem to find the solution I am looking for.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/635/44179

Answer (score 1):

The normal Ubuntu download that is not Wubi installs in a new partition.  Like just about every other Linux distribution, such as Red Hat, Debian, etc, it will look for any other operating system, like Windows, and create a dual boot configuration for all of them.

But be aware that once you install any of them, you can't simply erase it because the boot configuration file is on the last one installed.  If you delete it, Windows will not boot unless you restore its boot loader using either the original Windows boot disk, or a 3rd-party utility.

Comment: So if I used the wubi uninstaller I would have to restore the windows bootloader?

Comment: No, Wubi is special.  In fact, it was designed to make that easier, in that you can try it out, then uninstall it like a normal windows program instead of the more complicated method of restoring the bootloader using the windows install disk.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Ubuntu on separate partition without wiping the Windows boot loader. I have written a tutorial about it in details with snapshots [on my blog](http://a2zpctricks.blogspot.com/2012/09/ubuntu-dual-boot-with-windows-7-8-vista.html).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.