# How to uninstall windows xp using ubuntu 12.04 if they are in same partition?

Tags: 12.04, windows, delete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert Wubi install into regular install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install)

So I have installed Ubuntu 12.04.1 using windows installer and they are both installed in same location. Can anyone help me how to delete windows without harming linux?

GParted and Disk Utility doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have used Wubi to install Ubuntu inside your Windows XP machine which is a good way to test Ubuntu but if you want ONLY Ubuntu you will need to re-install on the actual hard-drive and overwrite Windows XP itself...  Wubi uses a file as a virtual hard-disk which only resides inside a WinXP install...