# Migrate 12.04 Wubi install to new partition with corrupted win7 install and small hard drive

Tags: wubi, windows-7

The move from Win7 to Ubuntu 12.04 has been honestly awesome. But I've come into a snag  because my Win7 inevitably broke.

I can still boot into Ubuntu even though Win7 is broken (won't boot, can't repair).

I'd like to Migrate Wubi to a real partition and forget about windows.

Presumably under normal conditions I would run the Ubuntu live CD, create a new partition then log back into my Wubi install and migrate using the script to the new partition. But I'm worried if I do that I'll break my current wubi set-up and be unable to migrate.

I have a small hard drive, only 75GB and unfortunately my backup drive recently died so can't migrate there first and transfer over either.

Does anybody have any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: Cant find any good information here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install ?

Comment: **Never, Never, Never,** fiddle with the OS when your backup drive is broken. Wait and save for a new backup drive.

Answer (score 0):

hmm how broke is windows, can you get to its run screen ?
If so open the Disk Management console by typing diskmgmt.msc at an elevated command prompt in windows that will safely shrink windows without damage to wubi.
I like using parted magic but downloading gparted in ubuntu live mode would work as well.

Than if all goes well u can completely move wubi into a real partion.
Than boot the live cd again and delete the windows partion and make your home partion larger by eating the unallocated space

=====
If windows does not boot try to take 5gb from windows partion in gparted or partedmagic than create the 2 partions one for the filesystem and the other for swap