# Changing from wubi to complete install?

Tags: wubi, live-usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert Wubi install into regular install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install)

So I have been successfully running ubuntu along side windows with the wubi installation but keep finding myself running out of space and wish to get rid of windows and solely go with ubuntu. Normally I would go straight ahead and use start up disk creator though at the present time I dont have any discs available and only have 2gb flash disc drives or a 120gb sata hard drive. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen [Ubuntu Community Help ?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/)

Here's what you're looking for: [MigrateWubi](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi)

Thanks