# Can I migrate from wubi Dual boot to Regular Dual boot?

Tags: boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert Wubi install into regular install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install)

12.04 LTS wubi "F:\ image on partition" and "windows7 on C:\"

Wanted to test before using full install. However I kinda customized the looks and got lots of SW installed and now I don't like the idea of reinstalling the whole thing all over again :D...

Due to previous cloning my broken 320GB HDD to 500GB HDD I had ca. 180GB unallocated which I made as NTFS and it's drive F:. I would like to make that drive ext with full ubuntu 12.04 but I'd like, if possible, to make my current wubi installation a full one.

Now I read that it's possible to migrate wubi to full. But..

Is it safe with Grub and windows 7 installed?

Is there alternative how to keep all the installation/current state of ubuntu
and get it to the new full install?

Comment: Please note the edits I made in the answer since first posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I am aware of to attempt to do what you are doing is to sync all of your software to Ubuntu Software Center and backup your files. Then delete the Wubi and install Ubuntu in the partion

Comment: There is a way, but it is difficult. See the above answer.

Comment: sounds good. But would it work also for the software not installed with software center? Manually installed .deb packages?

Comment: I believe so, yes

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `tar` to backup your /home, /etc, /usr, /bin, /sbin, /lib directories. After the new install you can then extract the "tarred" files to the proper directories.

Adapted from user Heliodode on Ubuntu Forums: [Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=35087&highlight=make%20a%20full%20back%20up%20using%20tar)

> Hi, and welcome to the Heliode guide to successful backing-up and
>   restoring of a Linux system!
>
> **Edited out:** interesting but unneeded banter.
>  
>   **1: Backing-up**
>  
>   **Edit:** more banter
>
> To do this, become root with
>
> `sudo su`
>
> and go to the root of your filesystem (we use this in our example, but
>   you can go anywhere you want your backup to end up, including remote
>   or removable drives.)
>
> `cd /`
>
> Now, below is the full command I would use to make a backup of my
>   system:
>
> `tar cvpzf backup.tgz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found
>   --exclude=/backup.tgz --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/sys /`
>
> **Edit add:** The file you create will be very large. You may wish to direct this backup to an external device. If you do then change the
>   file name (backup.tgz) to /media/*external-device*/backup.tgz  . Then,
>   exclude the /media directory ` --exclude=/media
>
> Now, lets explain this a little bit. The 'tar' part is, obviously, the
>   program we're going to use.
>
> 'cvpfz' are the options we give to tar, like 'create archive'
>   (obviously), 'preserve permissions'(to keep the same permissions on
>   everything the same), and 'gzip' to keep the size down.
>
> Next, the name the archive is going to get. backup.tgz in our example.
>
> Next comes the root of the directory we want to backup. Since we want
>   to backup everything; /
>
> Now come the directories we want to exclude. We don't want to backup
>   everything since some dirs aren't very useful to include. Also make
>   sure you don't include the file itself, or else you'll get weird
>   results. You might also not want to include the /mnt folder if you
>   have other partitions mounted there or you'll end up backing those up
>   too. Also make sure you don't have anything mounted in /media (i.e.
>   don't have any cd's or removable media mounted). Either that or
>   exclude /media.
>
> Well, if the command agrees with you, hit enter (or return, whatever)
>   and sit back&relax. This might take a while.
>
> Afterwards you'll have a file called backup.tgz in the root of your
>   filessytem, which is probably pretty large. Now you can burn it to DVD
>   or move it to another machine, whatever you like!
>
> **EDIT2:** At the end of the process you might get a message along the lines of 'tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors' or something,
>   but in most cases you can just ignore that.
>
> Alternatively, you can use Bzip2 to compress your backup. This means
>   higher compression but lower speed. If compression is important to
>   you, just substitute the 'z' in the command with 'j', and give the
>   backup the right extension. That would make the command look like
>   this:
>
> `tar cvpjf backup.tar.bz2 --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found
>   --exclude=/backup.tar.bz2 --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/sys /`
>
> **2: Restoring**  (In this case, after you do a full install. Make sure to use the same version of install disk as the system you are
>   backing up.)
>
> **Warning:** Please, for goodness sake, be careful here. If you don't understand what you are doing here you might end up overwriting stuff
>   that is important to you, so please take care!
>
> Once again, make sure you are root and that you and the backup file
>   are in the root of the filesystem.
>
> `sudo su`
>  `cd /`
>
> One of the beautiful things of Linux is that This'll work even on a
>   running system; no need to screw around with boot-cd's or anything. Of
>   course, if you've rendered your system unbootable you might have no
>   choice but to use a live-cd, but the results are the same. You can
>   even remove every single file of a Linux system while it is running
>   with one command. I'm not giving you that command though!
>
> Well, back on-topic. This is the command that I would use:
>
> `tar xvpfz backup.tgz -C /`
>
> Or if you used bz2;
>
> `tar xvpfj backup.tar.bz2 -C /`
>
> **WARNING:** this will overwrite every single file on your partition with the one in the archive!
>
> Just hit enter/return/whatever and watch the fireworks. Again, this
>   might take a while. When it is done, you have a fully restored Ubuntu
>   system! Just make sure that, before you do anything else, you
>   re-create the directories you excluded:
>
> `mkdir proc mkdir lost+found mkdir mnt mkdir sys` etc...
>
> And when you reboot, everything should be the way it was when you made
>   the backup!
>
> **2.1:** GRUB restore Now, if you want to move your system to a new harddisk or if you did something nasty to your GRUB (like, say,
>   install Windows), You'll also need to reinstall GRUB. There are
>   several very good howto's on how to do that here on this forum, so i'm
>   not going to reinvent the wheel. Instead, take a look [here](http://www.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=24113&highlight=grub%20restore).
>
> There are a couple of methods proposed. I personally recommend the
>   second one, posted by remmelt, since that has always worked for me.

Comment: Thanks.. But do I need to do some GRUB restoration? Wouldn't it screw my win7 installation?

Comment: Yes. since this would write the grub info from wubi you *might* have to boot to a live CD and run update-grub .

Comment: It wouln't screw your Windows7 install since grub recognizes it and will make an entry for it.

Comment: I guess I should also ask, do you understand partitioning and seting up a standard dual boot?