# Installed Ubuntu on separate partition using wubi, can I delete my Windows partition entirely?

Tags: boot, partitioning, 12.10, wubi

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 (updated to 12.10) on a separate partition from inside Windows 8 using WUBI.

I would like to use only Ubuntu. Can I simply delete the partition where Windows is located?

I'm using the Windows boot loader.

Comment: No you cannot, if you used Wubi. Please edit the question with some more info... like the output of `df -h` and `sudo fdisk -l` (that's a lower case `-L`) so it's clear what we are dealing with.

Comment: No. You would need to migrate your wubi installation to regular installation. This should help - http://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install

Comment: Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on /dev/loop0 4.5G 4.2G 392M 92% / udev 1.5G 4.0K 1.5G 1% /dev tmpfs 601M 812K 600M 1% /run none 5.0M 0 5.0M 0% /run/lock none 1.5G 340K 1.5G 1% /run/shm none 100M 68K 100M 1% /run/user /dev/sda3 15G 5.0G 10G 34% /host –

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to get rid of Windows altogether, it is best to do a fresh install using a live USB or live DVD.

However if you wish to keep settings and applications already installed in Ubuntu you may consider migrating it.

[This page explains how](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi) but in my opinion you're better off, backing up your data to an external drive and do a fresh install.

Comment: Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0      4.5G  4.2G  392M  92% /
udev            1.5G  4.0K  1.5G   1% /dev
tmpfs           601M  812K  600M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.5G  340K  1.5G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   68K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda3        15G  5.0G   10G  34% /host

Comment: Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000b2f3b
 Device Boot Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2  206848   266244095   133018624    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3 281190400   312575999    15692800  7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4 268324864   281190399     6432768  7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Comment: i dont know what any of this stuff is

Comment: All the more I suggest you backup everything and do a fresh install as I recommended.