# How to uninstall Windows after installing Wubi?

Tags: uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert Wubi install into regular install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install)

Okay so I'm not so great at this but I was trying to replace Windows Vista on my computer with Ubuntu. I thought I did this by going through the Windows Installer but it seems I have the "Wubi" version which isn't the same thing.

I was about to uninstall Windows through "OS Uninstaller" but I imagine this isn't a good idea if I just have Wubi, right?

Comment: you cant remove windows of your ubuntu is a wubi instalation.

wubi installs ubuntu as a "file" in your windows filesystem, so destroying the windows file system would destroy your linux

Comment: the 'how to convert' question might help with putting your ubuntu outside of the windows partition