# Delete Windows 7 after installing Wubi.exe

Tags: wubi, windows-7, uninstall

Long story short, I need Ubuntu on this net-book installed CRITICALLY by tomorrow. I don't have any flash drives, but the net-book already has Windows 7. If I install Wubi.exe, will I be able to get rid of Windows 7 and use the space that Windows 7 was in for Ubuntu? I still have more then enough space left to install Ubuntu, but for whats due tomorrow, I will not. I'm installing 12.4LTS. If you have any questions ask right away and I will answer because if I don't do this by tomorrow, my boss will probably kill me. I will be on this website until I get an answer that will help me.

Comment: Relax... I doubt your boss will kill you... unless you work for the Mafia or something....

Comment: I just bought a flash drive and did it using it and im writing this comment in the complete version, but thanks anyway, i leared how wubi works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wubi is a loop back "hack" if you will, this meaning that your Ubuntu will live on the Windows partition and when you boot, and tell it to boot to Ubuntu, it will tell the computer to look in the Windows partition for the Wubi install. Thus if you get rid of Windows you will also get rid of your loop back as it will no longer exist.

I would recommend going and buying a flash drive or 2 (1gb or larger) as cheap as they are these days. San Disk work really well, I have had a problem booting off a few PNY drives though so you might want to avoid those.

Short of that, you will be stuck using Wubi.

By the way, this is the best non-technical explanation I could come up with.

Answer (score 4):

You can shrink Windows (using it's Disk Management console) and then install Wubi and use that to create partitions and then migrate the Wubi install over to the new partitions. It's a bit long winded, but it's definitely doable. After that, you could remove the remaining Windows if it's important to remove all traces.

See [How to convert Wubi install into regular install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install)

Comment: This is possible? wow... made my head explode...

Comment: If things go south (and south is bad), you will still need a flash drive to fix any problems you may have sooner or later.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the way Wubi installs Ubuntu (within the Windows partition), I doubt you can delete Windows after installing Ubuntu.

Your best bet is likely going to be running out to your nearest electronics store and picking up a cheap flash drive and just doing a clean install. Alternatively, you may be able to do a network install if you have another computer that can host the installer.