# Wubi install Ubuntu key combinations not working

Tags: 12.10, wubi, freeze

I have installed wubi it is frozen but the key combinations suggested (https://wiki.edubuntu.org/WubiGuide#How_to_reboot_cleanly_even_when_the_keyboard.2BAC8-mouse_are_frozen) won't work.

It has frozen before and the combinations have worked but this time they don't. 
I am running 12.10. The computer froze while it was installing a software center app and I had the chrome webstore open,(in chromium) their is also a libre office text document open in the background.

I have already lost a wubi install by forced shutdown but now I cannot afford to corrupt the file system as windows is currently not working (long story). Any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> is not working and you've made sure you're doing it correctly *and* **there is no hard drive activity at all** - then I've powered off before with no issues.

But if you are running a Wubi install with a broken Windows and you don't have current, synchronized data - you are taking a lot of chances with that data. When you have free cloud-based storage services such as Ubuntu One, Google Drive, Mega.co.nz(?), DropBox and others, there really is no reason not to have backups.

Comment: Ok thanks powered on with no problems. I have my information backed up its just that I would not (easily) be able to reinstall ubuntu if it became corrupted.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to Migrate a Wubi install](http://askubuntu.com/a/36904/14916). You'll likely need an Ubuntu DVD/USB to partition, but after that you don't need to worry about Windows.