# Can I re-install windows without affecting Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, wubi, viruses

I Installed Ubuntu 12.04 using Wubi.
I still use Windows 7 from time to time and now I think I have a virus on it (system crash twice a day without a reason)

My question is, If I will re-install Windows, will it remove my Ubuntu installation as well? Is it possible at this point to remove Windows completely and allocate the hard-drive space only for Ubuntu?

Thanks so much

Comment: Reinstalling will likely remove the Wubi install depending on how you do it. See this for converting Wubi into a regular install: http://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put in the Windows 7 installation disk.

When loaded, choose your language, and click next.

[image: Image 1]

At the screen, click 'Install now.'

[image: Image 2]

Now, this is important. Click '**Upgrade**'.

[image: Image 3]

You will also need to [re-install grub.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)

That's all I need to tell you. Just follow the steps. It will have all your files.

Any errors, tell me.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's ok. Anytime.

Comment: Reinstalling grub won't work on a Wubi install. You're best to back it up or migrate prior to reinstalling Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can install windows, just be careful that you understand which partition is for Windows and your Ubuntu and swap partitions.

You will need to restore grub

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows