# expanding the current running operating system partition

Tags: 12.10, boot, partitioning, disk-management

I have dual booted my pc from windows to ubuntu 12.10v.
 I actually had done it by shrinking the *500GB* volume to half a part to windows and half to ubuntu.
 Now I am facing an issue called low disk space.
 How to extend my boot partition, sounds funny, because I already have a space capacity of *250GB* assigned for UBUNTU.

Here is my disk-free status

```
pradeep@:~$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0      17884496 16096924    879080  95% /
udev             1966728        4   1966724   1% /dev
tmpfs             790388      792    789596   1% /run
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             1975964      464   1975500   1% /run/shm
none              102400       16    102384   1% /run/user
/dev/sda5      233138172 19311152 213827020   9% /host
```

Now the */dev/sd5* captured my whole volume.. How to make it use for my root

Comment: It looks like you installed Ubuntu from within Windows using WUBI.exe. If this is the case, this question has been answered at [How to convert WUBI install to regular install?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install) Also see some of the [limitations of WUBI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_(Ubuntu_installer)#Limitations).