# Unstalling windows which installed ubuntu through wubi

Tags: 12.10, wubi, windows-7

I had a `windows7` installation on `C:`
I installed `ubuntu` through `wubi` on D:

Now I want to uninstall windows on `C:` and re-install it on `C:` only. Will it be okay to do it? Will my Ubuntu installation remain as it is? Is there something I need to take care of?

Comment: No, the user does not want to turn his Ubuntu into a regular installation. He wants to reinstall Windows, and make sure that he will still be able to boot into the Wubi-installed Ubuntu.

Comment: @bcbc: I don't want to turn it into a regular installation. I just want to make sure it works as normal.

Answer (score 1):

Well, re-installing windows is not going to delete the data in your ubuntu install, but it is going to undo the configuration in windows, including the boot loader.

You could try various backups or copying "D:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk" (or whatever), but as you are starting with a fresh install of Windows, why not go ahead and do a traditional installation of Ubuntu as well ?

[How to convert Wubi install into regular install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install)

You can decide what is easier (migration vs. fresh install), but, I highly suggest you back up your data first in case it goes wrong.

Comment: I don't want to turn it into a regular installation. I just want to make sure it works as normal.