# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Wubi Installation

Tags: 12.04, wubi, lts

I have just (finally) installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my Acer Aspire One netbook, using Wubi.

I have tried to install with a USB stick many times, but failed.

So, now I have a dual boot with Ubuntu and Windows 7. But I want to completely remove Windows 7, just to stay with my Ubuntu only. I have an Internet WiFi connection, but I can not use a USB stick or DVD.

Comment: you would better create another partition and install it from a usb/cd drive instead of using wubi.

Answer (score 1):

WUBI installs Ubuntu **within** your Windows machine.

You'd have to back up your files, then delete Windows and install Ubuntu, copying your files back afterwards.

Comment: Yeah, except he can't reinstall Ubuntu because he can't use a USB stick or DVD =). So his only option is to use the [script that migrates Wubi into a full installation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install).

Comment: Oh... Heh.. Good find Alaa.. I didn't catch that.. I forgot about that Wubi-move thing, a +1 to you sir.