# Dual Boot with WUBI Installer - reinstalling Windows

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7, wubi

I have installed Ubuntu using a Windows installer - Wubi - as a dual boot with Windows 7. Now I would like to reinstall Windows 7.

Is there any chance to retain Ubuntu? Any tweak available to make it as direct boot?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert Wubi install into regular install?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install)

Comment: Above is not really just a tweak, but does the full conversion to partitioned install. If reinstalling and not converting be sure to fully backup root.disk as that is all your wubi install. But best to convert to full install.