# Windows 8 dual boot problem

Tags: dual-boot

I have Windows 8 on a Dell XPS 12. I just reinstalled Windows 8 and have legacy boot, not longer UEFI. I used Wubi and installed Ubuntu. The laptop restarts. I chose Ubuntu and the screen turns purple for a second and I hear a beat and then the screen goes black and nothing happens. Did I do something wrong?

Also secure boot and quick boot.

Comment: please don't use wubi.It had issues like these.Try to install ubuntu and windows 8 on the same hard disk.

Comment: I tried to use the usb option. I chose try ubuntu and install but it would just go to a blank screen and nothing would happen.

Comment: did you use wubi to install ubuntu.

Comment: yes because when I first tried to use a usb with Ubuntu on it, it wouldn't install.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install you can follow this post to convert wubi install to regular install.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone said , it's probably the problem with the installation itself and not regarding bootloader, and use pendrivelinux to burn ubuntu to usb , since its slightly slower => less chances of failure/corruption.

At splash screen of dell , choose boot menu (I think its F12) otherwise enter setup and set priority to usb.

Then on partitioning screen , choose to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.

Comment: I used pendrivelinux and booted from the usb device. It didn't work.

Comment: I booted from the usb and a symbol popped up on the bottom of the screen. It then had me select a language. The it gave me a menu with lists to install, try, check for defects, etc. I selected install and try but both times the screen goes blank and nothing happens.